# unable to install from cpan: couldn't move file - No such File

Tags: perl, cpan

When trying to install `Devel::Camelcadedb` via cpan it errors when trying to install prereq Test2

```
Running install for module 'Test2::Tools::Spec'
Checksum for C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\id\E\EX\EXODIST\Test2-Suite-0.000129.tar.gz ok
Test2-Suite-0.000129/
Test2-Suite-0.000129/lib/
...
...
...
Couldn't move C:\Perl64\cpan\build\tmp-10864\Test2-Suite-0.000129\lib to C:\Perl64\cpan\build\Test2-Suit
e-0.000129-m8qIN8\lib: No such file or directory at C:\Perl64\lib/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 571.
```

I have tried installing Test2 on its own but get the same issue. Anyone any ideas. I am using perl Activestate on windows

Comment: What `perl` version are you using? Can you try [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) ? What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: seemed to get it working, I installed test2 via the activestate perl package manager, i also then installed Camelcadedb via that but it was not the most recent version. However once test2 was installed via ppm i was able to sintall camelcadedb via cpan

Answer (score -2):

First you should try to run your command with root rights.
1 - sudo su
2 - install module

And you can try out to install with perl-shell:
perl -e shell -MCPAN

Comment: I am using windows. I wrote that in my question So running as sudo is not an option for me. Also i solved it as writting in my comment last week

Comment: If you type `cpan` without arguments, you get the CPAN.pm shell.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed that sentence.